# Not able to read file content from google cloud storage in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When I try to read content of a file (plain text) from Google Cloud Storage (App Engine, Python, Standard Env) I get the following trace:

```
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

Although 'Share Publicly' is set, I am working in the default bucket (the application should have full permissions to my understanding) and I am able to write/upload content to the same file.

As additional info I am triggering the request from an http route using GAE development server.

Could you point me to the right direction ? :D

Code is below:

```
def getDatastoreClient():
    projectId = 'xxxxxx'
    return storage.Client(projectId)

def readFileFromBucket(filename):
    # Instantiates a client
    storage_client = getDatastoreClient()

    # Creates the new bucket
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(BUCKETNAME)
    blob = bucket.get_blob(filename)
    return blob.download_as_string()
```

Comment: What version of `requests` are you using?  Revert back to v2.3 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: wow! Actually it does help, what is this meaning? I have been using 2.17.3 and I also tried 2.18...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest versions of `requests` are not yet compatible with GCS.  For now, downgrade your `requests` package to v2.3.0.  Or, switch to using GAE's `urlfetch`